How do I prevent the hero image from coming out of the hero section when resizing the browser? Also, it becomes very tiny when resized
I'm having trouble with the hero image in the right section of my hero area. It overflows out of the section when I increase the browser size and becomes too small when the browser is minimized. I'm quite a beginner in CSS, need some help :(
I tried min-height, max-height, vh, nothing worked!
.hero-right is the image that isn't working properly


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: #1f2937;
  padding: 1rem 8rem;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1rem 8rem;
  height: 60vh;
  background: #1f2937;
  gap: 25px;
}

.hero-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.hero-right {
  max-width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#hero-img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #f9faf8;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  gap: 10px;
}

h1 {
  color: #f9f1f8;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: extra-bold;
}

.header-text,
li {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #e5e7eb;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  background-color: #3882f6;
  color: #e5e7eb;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 400px;
  gap: 20px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #1f2937;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  gap: 25px;
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid #3882f6;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text-below {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blockquote-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #e5e7eb;
  min-height: 400px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.blockquote {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #1f2937;
}

.blockquote-author {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.blockquote-author::before {
  content: "\\2014\\0020";
}

.call-to-action {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 150px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3882f6;
  margin: 60px 120px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  gap: 50px;
  color: #f9faf8;
  ;
}

.button {
  border: 2px solid #f9faf8;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #1f2937;
  color: #f9faf8;
}
<nav class="nav-bar">
  <div class="header-logo">Header Logo</div>
  <ul class="Links">
    <li><a>Header Link one</a></li>
    <li><a>Header Link two</a></li>
    <li><a>Header Link three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero-left">
    <h1>This website is awesome</h1>
    <p class="header-text">This is for a landing page yeepee</p>
    <button>Sign up</button>
  </div>

  <div class="hero-right">
    <img src="/images/hero.jpg" alt="soldering" id="hero-img" />
  </div>
</section>

<section class="middle">
  <h3>Some random information</h3>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <p class="text-below">
        this is some subtext under an illustration of image
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <p class="text-below">
        this is some subtext under an illustration of image
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <p class="text-below">
        this is some subtext under an illustration of image
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <p class="text-below">
        this is some subtext under an illustration of image
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="blockquote-box">
  <blockquote class="blockquote">
    <p class="blockquote-text">
      To be or not to be, which is the question..
    </p>
    <p class="blockquote-text blockquote-author">Gina</p>
  </blockquote>
</section>

<section class="call-to-action">
  <div class="left-action">
    <h2>Call to action! It's time!</h2>
    <p>Sign up by clicking that button right over there!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button>Sign up</button>
  </div>
</section>

<footer>Copyright © Gina 2024</footer>




If you use bootstrap you can use grid.
